# What is the correct way use of "using" in C#.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, using-statement

which approaches are correct about "using" (first or second)?

First:

```
using (DataTable dt = list.ToDataTable())
{
     dataList.DataSource = dt;
     dataList.DataBind();
}
```

Second:

```
 using (DataTable dt = list.ToDataTable())
 {
     dataList.DataSource = dt;
 }
 dataList.DataBind();
```

Comment: `DataTable` does not implement `IDisposable`, so you can't use it within `using` statement...

Comment: In second approach you are gonna call DataBind() on disposed object.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - really? I must be imagining the `Dispose()` and `Dispose(bool)` [methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) that it inherits from `MarshalByValueComponent`.

Comment: Ah a DataTable IS disposable, but it SHOULD NOT be used. This was a recommendation from Microsoft, calling the Disposabillity a mistake.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever wow, you got me! I only checked `DataTable` class signature...

Comment: Did you try out these two approaches yourself? The second should not actually work because you are using DataBind after the object has been disposed.

Comment: @ Amicable:Yes, I try them.They're worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well in your case it has to be the first approach otherwise you will dispose of the `DataTable` before it's been used (so `DataBind()` in the second would throw an exception).

In general though, you only need to keep code which uses the disposable object within the scope of the `using`.